# What does @ do?

Tags: php, html, request

I found [this tutorial](http://www.gethow.org/make-your-own-try-it-editor) on making a try it editor for a website.
I understood everything in the code except the @ in the **result.php**:

#### Result.php

```
<?php 
$myCode = @$_REQUEST["code"];
print $myCode ;
?>
```

Also I tried removing it from the code and nothing changed, so what does it do?

Comment: It makes you not know what your code did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ is a PHP error control operator

PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored

**Reference**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

**Example**

```
<?php
/* Intentional file error */
$my_file = @file ('non_existent_file') or
    die ("Failed opening file: error was '$php_errormsg'");

// this works for any expression, not just functions:
$value = @$cache[$key];
// will not issue a notice if the index $key doesn't exist.

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It ignores/suppresses error messages - see [Error Control Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in the PHP manual.

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

so any error in `$myCode = @$_REQUEST["code"];` will be ignored.